# Unable to find GlobalSQLite file for capacitor-community/sqlite in Ionic 5

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, ionic-framework, capacitor-plugin

In my Ionic 5 app, I am using the [capacitor-community/sqlite](https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite) plugin. I am successfully able to create and use an encrypted db with this plugin. To use encryption a `secret` is required and the following is maintained in the [official documentation](https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite) as of today.

> **Defining your own secret and newsecret keys (encryption only)**
>
> - in IOS, go to the Pod/Development    Pods/capacitor-sqlite/GlobalSQLite.swift file
> - in Android, go to    capacitor-sqlite/java/com.jeep.plugin.capacitor/cdssUtils/GlobalSQLite.java
>   and update the default values before building your app.
> - in Electron, go to YOUR_APP/electron/plugins/plugin.js-xxxx.js and    search for class GlobalSQLite and modify the this.secretand
>   this.newsecret parameters.

I have searched for files GlobalSQLite.swift and GlobalSQLite.java in IOS and android respectively but there are no such files present. Also, the file paths are not available. I am not sure how to get these files to set my secret in the app. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for the `GlobalSQLite.java` in `node_modules\@capacitor-community\sqlite\android\src\main\java\com\getcapacitor\community\database\sqlite\SQLite`. After changing the secrets you may need to sync the platforms with `ionic cap sync`.

The iOS and Electron files you also find there

Comment: Got the file. Thank you!